# Combine multple aggregation queries into a single query

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

How can I combine these four queries into a single query?

```sql
select count(ornon_id) as DEC_AUTH_Y from tbbu_policies where DECL_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'Y' and status_code = 'ACTI';
    
select count(ornon_id) as DEC_AUTH_N from tbbu_policies where DECL_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'N'and  status_code = 'ACTI';
    
select count(ornon_id) as INV_AUTH_Y from tbbu_policies where INV_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'Y' and status_code = 'ACTI';
    
select count(ornon_id) as INV_AUTH_N from tbbu_policies where INV_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'N'  and status_code = 'ACTI';
```

Comment: I want to run this code in one go

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN DECL_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'Y' THEN ornon_id END) as DEC_AUTH_Y,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN DECL_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'N' THEN ornon_id END) as DEC_AUTH_N,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN INV_AUTH_REQ_FLAG  = 'Y' THEN ornon_id END) as INV_AUTH_Y,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN INV_AUTH_REQ_FLAG  = 'N' THEN ornon_id END) as INV_AUTH_N
FROM   tbbu_policies
WHERE  status_code = 'ACTI';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case`-`when` based strategy with four columns, like this:

```
select
SUM(
CASE
    WHEN DECL_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'Y' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as firstcount,
SUM(
CASE
    WHEN DECL_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'N' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as secondcount,
SUM(
CASE
    WHEN INV_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'Y' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as thirdcount,
SUM(
CASE
    WHEN INV_AUTH_REQ_FLAG = 'N' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END) as fourthcount
from tbbu_policies
where status_code = 'ACTI' and
      (not (ornon_id is null));
```

Comment: This may not be quite the same as the OP is counting when `ornon_id` is not-`NULL` whereas this answer counts the rows regardless of whether they are `NULL` or not.

Comment: @MT0 thanks for pointing that out. Adjusted my `where` clause to cope with this.